# Docker : How to run a service and a terminal in one command?

Tags: docker

I'm running an apache server like this

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 php:apache /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUNDD
```

Then I determine the name of the container with

```
docker ps
```

and execute an interactive shell on the container with

```
docker exec -ti hungry_fermi bash
```

It works well, but I would like to do the same in one command. I've tried

```
docker run -ti -d -p 80:80 php:apache /bin/bash -c 'bash; apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
```

The problem is that, I don't obtain a terminal and the command returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying this:

```
docker run -ti -d -p 80:80 php:apache \
  /bin/bash -c 'bash; apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
```

There are several problems here.  First, you're using the `-d` command line option, which asks the docker client to detach and leave the container running.  You will never get an interactive shell when using `-d`.

Secondly, your command -- `bash; apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND` -- would run bash, wait for bash to exit, then run `httpd`.  You can instead do something like this:

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 php:apache \
  /bin/bash -c 'apachectl start; bash'
```

This would start Apache in the background (because there is no `-D FOREGROUND`), and then start bash...but I'm not really clear why you would want to do this, because now if you were to exit your shell the container would exit as well (taking Apache with it).

I think you are much better simply starting Apache the way you are now, and using `docker exec` to get a shell inside the container.

Comment: It's for testing configurations before to write them in my Dockerfile. Doing that in one command without manually inspect the ouptut of `docker ps` is useful. Thanks